# code first self referencing foreign key

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, code-first

I'm having a problems creating a self reference.

I have a class that looks like this

```
 public class User
{


    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentUser")]
    public string ParentUserName { get; set; }
    public User ParentUser { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<User> SubsetUsers { get; set; }     

}
```

and using Fluent API to Configure a Self Referencing Association:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(a => a.ParentUser)
    .WithMany(a=> a.SubsetUsers)
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.ParentUserName);
```

when i edit a user and want to select a user (`db.User.Find(SelectedUser.UserName)`) i get error :

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'User_ParentUser_Target' of the relationship 'AutomationDataLayer.User_ParentUser' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

Comment: I am not sure but: try to remove the  `[ForeignKey("ParentUser")]` attribute. It is redundant.

Comment: I remove it, but i get error again .

Comment: Check your code. I think you have defined the relation somewhere else too. The code given looks correct to me.

Comment: No, I have another class that have self referencing, and have same error for it.

Comment: Check the keys that are generated in Server Explorer. The code given is correct. I checked Alternatively: try to use this without any configuration: Change UserName in UserID and ParentUserName in ParentUserID. EF shhould then pick up the relationship by convention.

Comment: Thanks, I use `db.User.Single(e => e.UserName == SelectedUser.UserName)` Instead of `db.User.Find(SelectedUser.UserName)`, it is work but when i want reload it i use `db.Entry<User>(SelectedUser).Reload();` , i get error `Multiplicity constraint violated`

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle 2 way mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(a => a.SubsetUsers)
    .WithRequired(a => a.ParentUser)
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.ParentUserName);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(a => a.ParentUser)
    .WithMany(a=> a.SubsetUsers);
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i use this, i get error `The navigation property 'ParentUser' declared on type 'AutomationDataEntryModel.User' has been configured with conflicting multiplicities.`

Comment: @ar.gorgin You need to remove `[ForeignKey("ParentUser")]`

Comment: @ar.gorgin Updated. I think you need to only specify the foreign key in the has many mapping.

Comment: thanks, but get error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: 2 way mapping is unnecessary. I just checked on my own model that uses a 0..1 <-> * relation on self.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716754/multiplicity-constraint-violated). If I apply the problem there to your problem then the same User was added more than once to the SubsetUsers collection.